# googleapis throwing 'undefined' error in apirequest.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a problem with the NodeJs googleapis module.

My Simple Test:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var analytics = new google.analytics('v3');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var config = require('./config.js')

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(config.clientId, config.clientSecret);

// Retrieve tokens via token exchange explained above or set them:
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: config.accessToken,
  refresh_token: config.refreshToken
});

// get management list
analytics.management.accounts.list({ auth: oauth2Client }, function(err, response) {
  console.log(err)
  console.log(response)
});
```

My Result:

```
Type Error: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
    at createAPIRequest (/Users/gkburdett/Documents/Applications/maestro-and-scout/node_modules/googleapis/lib/apirequest.js:76:39)
    at Object.Analytics.management.accounts.list (/Users/gkburdett/Documents/Applications/maestro-and-scout/node_modules/googleapis/apis/analytics/v3.js:342:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gkburdett/Documents/Applications/maestro-and-scout/server/google/test/simpleTest.js:13:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

parameters.context.google is a blank object.

It works if I change apirequest.js line 76 to a blank object. I submitted an issue on GitHub, but I have a hard time believing I'm the only one having this problem if it's a problem with the library.

Answer (score 3):

Change line 2 from:

```
var analytics = new google.analytics('v3');
```

to:

```
var analytics = google.analytics('v3');
```

When calling `analytics.management.accounts.list` the context options being passed to `createAPIRequest` are out of scope to the initial `google` object.

Answer (score 0):

There was a method in my api with a name that started with "google" and it was overriding some internal config object of the library. I am not a guru to judge anyone but it seems like a poor design to mix internal and user-defined methods in one object